# ModuleNotFoundError in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

The questions was already asked, but I have problems applying the answers.

I want to use scipy in the jupyter notebook and when I run

```
!pip3 install scipy
```

it says that scipy is already installed. When I try importing it now I get the ModuleNotFoundError message. One solution to this question was that the path in the notebook is different and one should change it with

```
import sys
sys.path.append('your-path')
```

The problem is I don't understand what is happening here and I actually can't find the path of my python packages. I am using a Macbook with macOS 10.15.5 and python 3.8.3.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different pythons, point to the correct one, and run.

Mac since built on top of linux comes with default python 2.7.

So, find which python you have installed python package scipy.

Then, Point your IDE to it and run it, by changing settings.

You can find python by using
`where python` in terminal.

Then run

```
/Your/python/here/python* -c "help('modules')"
```

This will display if the python you're running has the package installed or not.

Finding where it is, is upto you. But pretty sure, that's the issue here.

Comment: So I get /usr/bin/python as path from where python. Then what do I run? ```/usr/bin/python/python* -c "help('moduls')" ```?

Comment: No you run ```/usr/bin/python -c 'help("modules")'``` and see if it has your scipy module. It definitely won't, you need to find where your other python for jupyter notebook is and run from that.

Comment: Or you can Just run jupyter notebook from terminal and run from there.

Comment: When I run this for just python it lists scipy. For python3 it does not list any packages even the ones I used with python3.

Comment: I am always running jupyter notebook from the terminal

Comment: Good. Then if you want to use it on python 3.8, then install with command ```/your/python3.8/location/python -m pip install scipy``` and then run it.

Comment: I can already use it with python 3.8.3, but not when using jupyter notebook.  If i run python scripts in terminal with python3 scipy is working without any issues.

Comment: I thought you might have figured the answer by now. Install jupyter notebook on your required version of python and then run it, otherwise install a kernel spec and run it